# Why does the activity to collect username and/or password launch automatically with a custom account authenticator in Android?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am following this [guide](https://developer.android.com/training/id-auth/authenticate#RequestToken) and I am confused. The activity that I created to collect username and/or password gets called without it being called the way shown here:

```
private inner class OnTokenAcquired : AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> {
    override fun run(result: AccountManagerFuture<Bundle>) {
        val launch: Intent? = result.getResult().get(AccountManager.KEY_INTENT) as? Intent

        if (launch != null) {
            startActivityForResult(launch, 0)
        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking that `OnTokenAcquired` parameter from `am.getAuthToken()` only supplies token when successfully retrieved. My two questions are:

1. Why is the activity I created to collect user details called without me launching it as in the code example above?
2. If it is launched automatically by the OS, then my do they show a way to launch it on the guide.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone has the same problem. I used the wrong `am.getAuthToken()` method overload. I called the one that takes `Activity` as an argument. [This is the method I was supposed to use.](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager#getAuthToken(android.accounts.Account,%20java.lang.String,%20android.os.Bundle,%20boolean,%20android.accounts.AccountManagerCallback%3Candroid.os.Bundle%3E,%20android.os.Handler))

Also note that, `onActivityResult()` is deprecated.